# Отладка dll и doesn't contain the architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, delphi, dll, отладка, clion

В Clion собираю 64-битную dll. Tollchain Visual Studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проект успешно компилируется. Для отладки использую Win64 хост приложение, откомпилированное на Delphi. Прописал это приложение в редакторе конфигурации и при запуске отладки получаю сообщение

> 'Project.exe' doesn't contain the architecture x86_64
> Process finished with exit code 0

Само приложение без отладчика (или из под отладчика Visual Studio) запускается и загружает мою dll.

Чего не хватает для счастья?

---

Проверил, если подсунуть 32-битное приложение (в порядке теста), то получаю такое сообщение

> 'Project.exe' doesn't contain the architecture i386
> Process finished with exit code 0

**Update**

Собрал пустой проект на Delphi

```pascal
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

begin
end.
```

При запуске его из под отладчика как хост-приложение получаю ту же ошибку.

При запуске в качестве хост приложения пустого проекта, собранного в Visual Studio

```c
int main()
{
}
```

отладчик запускается без ошибок

При указании конкретной платформы получаю ошибки сборки

- store, uwp

  > error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RoInitialize referenced in function __scrt_initialize_winrt
- onecore

  > Cannot load Visual C++ environment from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat:
  > [ERROR:vcvarsall.bat] Invalid argument found : onecore

Comment: Платформа не выбирается? Почему графа платформа - пусто?

Comment: @nick_n_a Она может быть [пустой](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-windows.html#msvc-compiler)  `Platform (store, uwp, onecore, or leave it blank)`, Я собираю обычное Win64 приложение

Comment: @nick_n_a При указании любой платформы проект вообще не собирается

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65897450/debug-dll-and-doesnt-contain-the-architecture-x86-64

Comment: Почему бы не попробовать использовать Visual Studio?

Comment: @user7860670 Сейчас для отладки ее и использую. Но хотелось переехать на Clion, т.к IDE на порядок удобнее

Comment: При указании платформы не собирается - боюсь нужно внимательно читать журнал output, и убирать ошибки. Также можно попробовать через msbuild собирать - но по сути будет тоже самое, только через консоль.

Comment: @nick_n_a Я добавил ошибки в вопрос

Comment: __imp_RoInitialize -мне это напоминает чего-то CoInitializе.Но это не так. Такое лечится такими способами. 1. Найдите официальный lib, и включаете его в сборку (можно даже сквозным поиском файлов в *.lib). 2. Находите dll c RoInitialize, снимите с него lib (утилита implib ) и включите в сборку. 3. Создаём def файл, и подключаем dll руцями. Почитайте тут https://coderoad.ru/16466641/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-RoInitialize-RoUninitialize

Comment: @nick_n_a Какой официальный либ? Обратили внимание на вызывающую функцию? `__scrt_initialize_winrt` Зачем мне WinRT в проекте? Платформа это точно путь в никуда

Comment: @nick_n_a Debug не то, чтобы не работает. Дебаггер не может запустить хост приложение, потому что считает, что оно собрано под другую архитектуру

Comment: А x64 не получится собрать, только amd64? Я почему то подумал что платформа это x86/x64. Может дебагер ваш x64 умеет, а amd64 не умеет?

Comment: @nick_n_a x64 и amd64 это [одно и то же](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). Доступные архитектуры: x86, amd64, arm, x86_amd64, x86_arm, amd64_x86, amd64_arm

Comment: Это заморочки отладчика LLDB, похоже, что он не находит какой-то специфичной для него отладочной информации в exe, вот и ругается. Попробуйте использовать GDB.

Comment: @zed Из доки Clion `The MSVC toolchain debugger is implemented on top of LLDB`. Я правильно понимаю, что для MSVC GDB недоступен?

Comment: Да, действительно. Нужно переключаться на MinGW для отладки.